# Dynamic refs on file input are empty

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

I am trying to setup a dynamic file uploading system in a nuxt3 app:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="element in elements">
        {{ element.id }}
      <input type="file" name="" id="" :ref="element.inputRef" />
    </div>
    <button @click="onClick">click</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    const elements = [
        { inputRef: ref<HTMLInputElement>(), id: 1 },
        { inputRef: ref<HTMLInputElement>(), id: 2 },
    ];

    const onClick = () => {
        elements.forEach((elem) => {
            const img = elem.inputRef.value;
            console.log(img);
        });
    };
</script>
```

This is a basic example but it does not work. When I select one file per input and then click on the button, the console log displays the right inputs but without any file.

Here is the package:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Have somebody an idea of the problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to upload all the files using the `onClick` handler.
In your `const img = elem.inputRef.value`, you are missing this `[0].files[0]`

It should be `const img = elem.inputRef.value[0].files[0];` to locate the uploaded files.

```js
const onClick = () => {
elements.forEach((elem) => {
  const img = elem.inputRef.value[0].files[0];
  selecedtImages.value.push(URL.createObjectURL(img))
});
};
```

I update your code and created an example. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-kgrs4i?file=app.vue